# Redirecting from IP address to domain name in HTTPS via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to Canonicate an IP to redirect to the domain name, but for some reasons it won't work and constantly having https://www.111.111.111.11.

Here is what I am using in my .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 #Uncomment lines below when uploading to the live server
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.111\.11$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.org$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)example\.org$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.org[L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example\.org/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|tif|js|css|xls|xlsx|zip|rar|pdf|ods|ots)$ - [F]
```

Additionally, plesk takes care of a safe SEO redirect from `example.org` to `www.example.org` and also from `http` to `https`.

I am not very familiar with .htaccess rules, but even to me it looks like I have some unnecessary lines in there.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In public directory, you must be sure that 000-default.conf file has AllowOverride All set, so the settings in your .htaccess file will be used.

Use these following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.22\.33\.44$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what about the rest of the conditions?

Comment: also, when I am accessing the site via IP only before redirect I have ssl warning asking to allow connection or deny